# Generating expression tree for a subproperty test

Tags: c#, linq

I want to generate a LambdaExpression for a statement like this :

```
Adress (p => p.Person.Name == "Mike")
```

where `Person` is a class which have a **Name** property.

I can't achieve this with `Expression.Property`.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You should show the code you've *tried*.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the type of p being PersonContainer:

```
    // p => p.Person.Name == "Mike"
ParameterExpression par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(PersonContainer), "p");
BinaryExpression beEq = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.Property(
        Expression.Property(par, "Person"), 
        "Name"),
    Expression.Constant("Mike"));

Expression<Func<PersonContainer, bool>> expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<PersonContainer, bool>>(beEq, par);
```